# Commutativity up to transposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, dynamical-systems, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have two square matrices $A, B$ for which the following property holds:

$$AB= (BA)^\top$$

Linear time-invariant systems have the property $AB=BA$, i.e., it is said that they commute. In my case, up to a transposition. Does this phenomenon have a particular name / arise in some specific scientific fields?

Comment: $$(BA)^{T}=A^{T}B^{T}.$$ So your equality is true, in particular, for any $A,B$ symmetric.

Comment: In any event, rewriting this as: $$AB=A^TB^T,$$ I wouldn't really use the word commutativity here. It is ... something, but not sure what I'd call it. Would be interested in cases of non-symmetric $A,B.$

Comment: Not all LTI systems have the property $AB=BA$. Consider $A\in R^{2\times 2}$ and $B \in R^{2\times 1}$ then $AB \in R^{2\times 1}$ but $BA$ is undefined because of dimension mismatch.